# Multiple std::map.insert()'s using the same std::pair of references, but with new values results in incorrect map values. Why and how to fix?

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, stdmap, std-pair

Multiple std::map.insert()'s using the same std::pair but with new values results in incorrect map values.  How can I use a single struct and references without creating this behavior?

```
#include <iostream>  // c++17 gcc 8.3.0-6 debian
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
using std::endl, std::cout, std::cerr;
struct Struct1 {
    int         s1_int1 {}, s1_int2 {};
    std::string s1_str1 {};
    struct Key {
        decltype (s1_int1) & key_part1;
        decltype (s1_int2) & key_part2;
    } key   { s1_int1, s1_int2 };
    struct Value {
        decltype (s1_str1) & value_part1;
    } value { s1_str1 };
    struct Compare {
        bool operator()( Key const & lhs, Key const & rhs) const {
            return std::tie( lhs.key_part1, lhs.key_part2 ) < std::tie( rhs.key_part1, rhs.key_part2 );
        }
    };
    void print (std::string message) const {
        cerr<<message<<">> s1_int1:"<< s1_int1<<", s1_int2:"<<s1_int2<<", s1_str1:"<<s1_str1<<endl;
    }
};
void r_print( std::pair<Struct1::Key,Struct1::Value> const & pair, bool is_inserted ) {
    cerr<<"is_inserted:"<<is_inserted<<", key.key_part1:"<<pair.first.key_part1<<", key.key_part2:"<<pair.first.key_part2<<", value.s1_str1:"<<pair.second.value_part1<<endl;
};
int main()
{
    std::map<Struct1::Key, Struct1::Value, Struct1::Compare > my_map {};
    Struct1 map_value1 {11,12,"s13"}, map_value2 = {21,22,"s23"};
    map_value1.print("map_value :12");
    auto const r1 = my_map.insert( {map_value1.key,map_value1.value} );
    r_print( *r1.first, r1.second );
    for (auto & [key,value]:my_map )
        cerr<< "key.key_part1:"<<key.key_part1<<", key.key_part2:"<<key.key_part2<<", value.s1_str1:"<<value.value_part1<<endl;

    map_value2.print("map_value2:22");
    auto const r2 = my_map.insert( {map_value2.key,map_value2.value} );
    r_print( *r2.first, r1.second );
    for (auto & [key,value]:my_map )
        cerr<< "key.key_part1:"<<key.key_part1<<", key.key_part2:"<<key.key_part2<<", value.s1_str1:"<<value.value_part1<<endl;

    map_value1.s1_int1 = 31; map_value1.s1_int2 = 32; map_value1.s1_str1 = "s33";
    map_value1.print("map_value :31");
    auto const r3 = my_map.insert( {map_value1.key,map_value1.value} );
    r_print( *r3.first, r1.second );
    for (auto & [key,value]:my_map )
        cerr<< "key.key_part1:"<<key.key_part1<<", key.key_part2:"<<key.key_part2<<", value.s1_str1:"<<value.value_part1<<endl;
    cout << "###" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the output note how the map is built and then broken on the last insert due to the re-use of map_value1.  I must be misunderstanding std::map, or something beyond that.

I think I partially understand why this may be occurring since the map is apparently not making a copy.  But I have not observed this behavior when using std::vector.push_back().  As I read the cppreference entries for those member functions, I don't see how the descriptions would inform me of the different behavior.  Also I presume the c++ containers would offer similar behavior in the creation of container elements.

A simple answer some might suggest is to not make use of references in Struct1::Key, however I'm trying to have the top level data members be both easily accessible in the struct and also to easily create the pair for insertion into the std::map.

I suppose I could force a copy somehow, which is what I'm trying to avoid by using references. Or create an "new" variable for every insertion, but that seems unnecessary and might cause memory leaks or dangling pointers if done incorrectly (an error I could quite easily make).

The overall goal is to create in-memory database-like functionality.

I appreciate any insights you can offer.

Output:

```
map_value :12>> s1_int1:11, s1_int2:12, s1_str1:s13
is_inserted:1, key.key_part1:11, key.key_part2:12, value.s1_str1:s13
key.key_part1:11, key.key_part2:12, value.s1_str1:s13
map_value2:22>> s1_int1:21, s1_int2:22, s1_str1:s23
is_inserted:1, key.key_part1:21, key.key_part2:22, value.s1_str1:s23
key.key_part1:11, key.key_part2:12, value.s1_str1:s13
key.key_part1:21, key.key_part2:22, value.s1_str1:s23
map_value :31>> s1_int1:31, s1_int2:32, s1_str1:s33
is_inserted:1, key.key_part1:31, key.key_part2:32, value.s1_str1:s33
key.key_part1:31, key.key_part2:32, value.s1_str1:s33
key.key_part1:21, key.key_part2:22, value.s1_str1:s23
key.key_part1:31, key.key_part2:32, value.s1_str1:s33
###
```

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to this:

```
struct S {
  int m;
  int& r = m;
};

S s1{42};
S s2{s1};
s1.m = 84;
std::cout << s2.r;  // prints 84
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/CBZ14140)

You have a structure that contains "normal" members and reference members. The (implicitly defined) default constructor, as well as aggregate initialization, initialize the latter to refer to the former. You appear to assume that the latter are, or should be, **always** initialized to refer to the former - but that's not the case. This structure also has an implicitly defined copy constructor, and that one performs member-wise copy - non-reference members of the copy get the same value as non-reference members of the original, while reference members of the copy are initialized to refer to the same objects as reference members of the original.

In my example, first `s1` is initialized with `s1.m == 42` and `s1.r` referring to `s1.m`. Then `s2` is copy-initialized from it; the result is that `s2.r` refers to `s1.m`, not `s2.m`. Then `s1.m` is modified, and `s2.r` dutifully reflects this modification.

Same thing happens with your `Struct1` and, perhaps more importantly, `Struct1::Key`. The structure is copied into the map, and the reference members in the copy end up referring to the non-reference members in the original, not the copy. Then by updating members in the original, you effectively modify the key in the copy, at which point your program exhibits undefined behavior - the map relies on ordering of keys to be stable, and instead you are reordering them right under its feet.

---

It's not clear how to salvage your approach, and frankly, it doesn't seem worth salvaging. You appear to believe that references are free, but in fact references are typically implemented as pointers underneath. A pair of references would likely use as much, or more, memory than a pair of ints (print `sizeof(Struct1)` and `2*sizeof(int) + sizeof(std::string)`; that might prove illuminating). You are not saving anything by copying references over if you just copied ints, but you are introducing major headaches.

Comment: Igor, Thank you for your detailed analysis.  I do specifically want references because, as of what I noted here: >>A simple answer some might suggest is to not make use of references in Struct1::Key, however I'm trying to have the top level data members be both easily accessible in the struct and also to easily create the pair for insertion into the std::map.<<

Comment: Igor, Yes a reference is a pointer and a pointer is an int (roughly speaking), but please understand that the sample code 'int' might be a 'long string' in a database key and then a pointer would be smaller.  I also want the values to be synchronized to allow dual access to the database row, so a ref seemed perfect for that.  The reason for that is I want the code to be usable by an ORM or Sqlite and they seem to like simple records ie. structs.

Comment: Igor,  Thank you for your example.  I had thought that the map would make a copy and that the ref would not break the map.  I was wrong. I do wonder why not, or how the map could have given me a compile time error, or even a run time error (yes the latter would be slow).

Comment: @GrantRostig: The only error was that you mutated a key (or rather something it referenced) in a way that affected its comparison order.  It’s rather expensive (and impossible in general) to check that, so it doesn’t.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you expected the map to somehow make a deep copy of the key, and store actual values internally and not just references. At the same time, you are concerned that the key values may be large and expensive to copy, and introduce references to avoid data duplication (while, again, believing that the map should somehow automatically duplicate that same data). I don't understand how you can reconcile these two contradicting ideas. I must admit I'm still not sure why you insist on using references here, what specific goal you imagine they will help achieve.

Comment: @DavisHerring, thank you, you are correct, but the ref to the value string also caused a problem, not just the key.  I noticed that behavior during further debugging.

Comment: @GrantRostig: That’s not an *error*, though—you just didn’t do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that std::map requires value_types.  I had references to values.  To fix it I simply exchanged the references with the referenced values.  Now the key and value are no longer references.  There may well be a better explanation for the exact problem, but I don't really know it.

```
#include <iostream>  // c++17 gcc 8.3.0-6 debian
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
using std::endl, std::cout, std::cerr;
struct Struct1 {
    struct Key {
        int key_part1;
        int key_part2;
    } key;
    struct Value {
        std::string value_part1;
    } value;
    int & s1_int1 {key.key_part1}, & s1_int2 {key.key_part2};
    std::string & s1_str1 {value.value_part1};
    struct Compare {
        bool operator()( Key const & lhs, Key const & rhs) const {
            return std::tie( lhs.key_part1, lhs.key_part2 ) < std::tie( rhs.key_part1, rhs.key_part2 );
        }
    };
    void print (std::string message) const {
        cerr<<message<<">> s1_int1:"<< s1_int1<<", s1_int2:"<<s1_int2<<", s1_str1:"<<s1_str1<<endl;
    }
};
void r_print( std::pair<Struct1::Key,Struct1::Value> const & pair, bool is_inserted ) {
    cerr<<"is_inserted:"<<is_inserted<<", key.key_part1:"<<pair.first.key_part1<<", key.key_part2:"<<pair.first.key_part2<<", value.s1_str1:"<<pair.second.value_part1<<endl;
};
int main()
{
    std::map<Struct1::Key, Struct1::Value, Struct1::Compare > my_map {};
    Struct1 map_value1 {11,12,"s13"} , map_value2 {21,22,"s23"};
    map_value1.print("map_value :12");
    auto const r1 = my_map.insert( {map_value1.key,map_value1.value} );
    r_print( *r1.first, r1.second );
    for (auto & [key,value]:my_map )
        cerr<< "key.key_part1:"<<key.key_part1<<", key.key_part2:"<<key.key_part2<<", value.s1_str1:"<<value.value_part1<<endl;

    map_value2.print("map_value2:22");
    auto const r2 = my_map.insert( {map_value2.key,map_value2.value} );
    r_print( *r2.first, r1.second );
    for (auto & [key,value]:my_map )
        cerr<< "key.key_part1:"<<key.key_part1<<", key.key_part2:"<<key.key_part2<<", value.s1_str1:"<<value.value_part1<<endl;

    map_value1.s1_int1 = 31; map_value1.s1_int2 = 32; map_value1.s1_str1 = "s33";
    map_value1.print("map_value :31");
    auto const r3 = my_map.insert( {map_value1.key,map_value1.value} );
    r_print( *r3.first, r1.second );
    for (auto & [key,value]:my_map )
        cerr<< "key.key_part1:"<<key.key_part1<<", key.key_part2:"<<key.key_part2<<", value.s1_str1:"<<value.value_part1<<endl;
    cout << "###" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
map_value :12>> s1_int1:11, s1_int2:12, s1_str1:s13
is_inserted:1, key.key_part1:11, key.key_part2:12, value.s1_str1:s13
key.key_part1:11, key.key_part2:12, value.s1_str1:s13
map_value2:22>> s1_int1:21, s1_int2:22, s1_str1:s23
is_inserted:1, key.key_part1:21, key.key_part2:22, value.s1_str1:s23
key.key_part1:11, key.key_part2:12, value.s1_str1:s13
key.key_part1:21, key.key_part2:22, value.s1_str1:s23
map_value :31>> s1_int1:31, s1_int2:32, s1_str1:s33
is_inserted:1, key.key_part1:31, key.key_part2:32, value.s1_str1:s33
key.key_part1:11, key.key_part2:12, value.s1_str1:s13
key.key_part1:21, key.key_part2:22, value.s1_str1:s23
key.key_part1:31, key.key_part2:32, value.s1_str1:s33
###
```